# ckmeans divide and conquer technique

Tags: r, algorithm, k-means

I was going through the ckmeans algorithm https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Wang+Song.pdf
I understood the Dynamic Programming approach to fill the matrices and get clusters. The time complexity is **O(kn^2)** as described in above PDF.

An improvement of this algorithm exists, which uses divide and conquer technique to fill the matrices. Time complexity reduces to **O(knlog(n))** I am unable to understand it from the code that exists for it https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics/blob/master/src/ckmeans.js

I have understood most of it, but the part where actual **log(n)** part comes. i.e from line [L95](https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics/blob/master/src/ckmeans.js#L95) to [L123](https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics/blob/master/src/ckmeans.js#L123)

Please help just understand the gist of what is happening here.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MrFlick oh ok. Thanks :)